# Jquery bypassing click events based on function parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a function that I need to run when I pass it an optional parameter but it's main action the AJAX call is triggered by a click event. I have tried the trigger() function to no success. What is the best way to handle this situation?

```
function call_stuff()
{
    $items = [];
    $(this).closest('tr').children().each(function () {
        $items.push($(this).text());
    });
    do_stuff($items);

}
```

---

```
function do_stuff(items) {

    if (typeof items === 'undefined') {
        //regular execution listen for click command
        // use $(this) for ajax data
    } else {
        //ignore click command, run ajax function.
        //use $items for ajax data

    }

    $(".tabs-parent li a, .tabs-child li a").click(function () {
        //the ajax call I need to run:
        $.ajax({
            data: {}
        })

    });


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relying on triggering events to execute some logic on demand is a common design mistake in my opinion. Your design will be cleaner and more flexible by encapsulating the behaviour in another function first, which you can then invoke at will.

```
function doSomething() {
    console.log('do something');
}

//adding the handler
$('#myEl').click(function () {
    doSomething();
});

//or without the adapter function it not necessary
$('#myEl').click(doSomething);

//calling at will
doSomething();
```

*Note: I am not advocating to declare functions in the global namespace. You should keep your code modular and correctly scoped.*

Comment: Yes this is interesting concept but then I would have to pass over references to $(this) every time a click is triggered.

Comment: @Edward Well use the same approach and encapsulate the logic you want to run in a function that's not part of the handler. I do not see what's the issue. Your functions should follow the single responsability principle. It then makes it easy the execute just what you need to execute without any code duplication.